# How to fix Preg replace problem with escape character

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace function to get redirect url.But it is not replacing properly.

I am trying below code

```
$key = 'acme/(.*)/(.*)';
$val = '\Acme\Blog\Controllers\$1::$2';
$uri = 'acme/Home/hello1';
$redirect = preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', $val, $uri);
```

The expected output is

```
\Acme\Blog\Controllers\Home::hello1
```

but getting output is

```
\Acme\Blog\Controllers$1::hello1
```

Comment: Try changing `$val` to `\Acme\Blog\Controllers\\\$1::$2`

Comment: is it possible with changing pattern value ?

Comment: I'm not following what you mean?

Comment: I am not supposed to change $val , $uri values ,so is there any another way?

Comment: The \ is escaping the $

Comment: _"I am not supposed to change $val "_ - Not even if it's wrong?

Comment: So, all backslashes in the pattern should be doubled? Use `preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $val), $uri);`

Answer (score 0):

use [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

> Code:

```
$key = 'acme/(.*)/(.*)';

$val = preg_quote('\\Acme\\Blog\\Controllers\\') . '$1::$2';
$uri = 'acme/Home/hello1';
$redirect = preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', $val, $uri);

echo $redirect;
```

> Result:

```
\Acme\Blog\Controllers\Home::hello1
```

> Note:

This is not a valid path:

```
'\Acme\Blog\Controllers\$1::$2';
```

Because backslash `\` needs escaping with another backslash `\` this is at the string level. If you want to create a string containing single backslash you need to put two of them.

```
$singleBackslash = '\\';
```

since backslash is treated as escape code this will give you parse error:

```
$singleBackslash = '\';
```

because backslash escaped ending `'`

if you want to have a backslash in regex then you need to escape it once again that's why I used preg_quote() on already escaped backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

All backslashes in the pattern you have must be doubled because a backslash in the replacement pattern is considered a special char: it escapes dollar signs so that if a number comes after `\$` it could not be parsed as a backreference.

So, all you need is

```
preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $val), $uri)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/cNQel):

```
$key = 'acme/(.*)/(.*)';
$val = '\Acme\Blog\Controllers\$1::$2';
$uri = 'acme/Home/hello1';
$redirect = preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $val), $uri);
echo $redirect;
```

Ouput:

```
\Acme\Blog\Controllers\Home::hello1
```